# Time independent harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

I have been trying to use the Schrodinger equation to solve a harmonic oscillator problem, to find expressions for E and B. Just can't finish the end of it.

I have the equation, which is correct

$$ x^2(mw^2-4\hbar^2B^2)-2\hbar^2B-2Em=0 $$

The advice I have been given is this is of the form $ Ax^2+b=0 $ in which order to be true requires both A and B to be zero. That is two conditions in the two unknowns E and B which allow you to solve the equation.

Really not sure what to do. Up to this line of working so far is correct I have been told.

This is my wave function

$ \psi(x)=A\exp(-Bx^2)$

Then I have to use this equation

$${(\hbar^2/2m)}(-2B+4B^2x^2)\psi+V\psi=E\psi $$

The $\psi$ will cancel out and you arrive with some rearranging at 
$$ x^2(mw^2-4\hbar^2B^2)-2\hbar^2B-2Em=0 $$

Comment: What is $B$ here?  The quantum harmonic oscillator is generally defined by time independent Schrodinger equation $\left(\frac{1}{2m}\hat P^2 + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 \hat X^2 \right) \psi = E\psi$, so I'm not sure where you're coming from.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you did and what you are asking without some context.  How did you arrive at that expression?  What is $B$?

Comment: Should this be $b$ rather than $B$?

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry not very used to this yet.

Comment: Your final equation comes out of applying the Hamiltonian to your wavefunction.  Because the right hand side is $0$ and $E$ is constant, the terms in various powers of $x$ must separately be $0$.  From the coefficient of $x^2$ you find $B$ and then use this to find E in terms of $\hbar, w$ and $m$.

Answer (score 1):

If the initial conditions apply to the equation $$Ax^2+B=0$$

We the get 2 equations

1) $A=mw^2-4\hbar^2B^2=0$

2)$B=-2(\hbar^2B+Em)=0$

From 1)  We get $$B=(w/2\hbar)\sqrt{m} $$

From 2)  We get $$E=-(\hbar w)/\sqrt{m}$$